# What is the difference between SQL Server Network Configuration and SQL Native Client Configuration?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When we set up SQL Server configuration, there are two options:

- Sql Server Network Configuration
- Sql Native Client Configuration

[image: sql server configuration manager screen]

both of them have four same connection options.

When we read the help manual of SQL Server for native clients, it states:

> The settings configured in SQL Server Native Client Configuration, are
>   used on the computer running the client program. When configured on
>   the computer running SQL Server, they affect only those client
>   programs running on the server.

I do not understand this definition fully.

What is the difference between SQL Server Network Configuration and SQL Native Configuration and when are they used?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `SQL Server Network Configuration` is for configuring the SQL Server process, i.e. the actual database server, which is a Windows Service.
- `SQL Server Native Client Configuration` is for configuring the SQL Server Client tools, e.g. SQL Server Management Studio, which is an executable program.

Keep in mind that SQL Server Client tools can connect either to the local machine (`localhost` or `.`), or to a remote machine.

Comment: So what is the meaning or difference of changing either sql server network tcp ip configuration or native client tcp ip configuration

Comment: The first configures the allowable protocols for `incoming` connections to the database server running on this machine. The second configures the allowable protocols for `outgoing` connections, in prioritized order, from the client tools on this machine to a server (either on this machine or other machines.)

Comment: For a server application, incoming port is important, all applications want to connect to this app on this incoming port. Why does sql server configure clients protocols , because we specify ports on a client application. It seems unnecessary. Why is native client configuration required. Thank you very much for informing us

Comment: It's not the `server` part of SQL Server that offers configuration of client protocols, it's the `client` tools, which may just as well run on a client machine like a developer laptop, without the server part installed.

Comment: I know this is old but I have a question about this. Does Native Client Configuration include things like web applications (on different machine) that try to connect to the SQL Server?